# How does a Python module that contains class of same name work when imported?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I have recently been using web.py for some simple web applications in Python. I thought I understood how import statements, packages and modules worked but now I am a little confused.

According to web.py's API it says that the class `application` is located inside the module `web.application`. In order to use this class, the tutorial gives examples such as

```
import web
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

What confuses me is how I am creating an instance of the `application` class using `web.application`. If there exists a class `application` that is **inside** a module named `application` within the web package, from what I have learned I would expect to have to do something as such :

`web.application.application(urls, globals())`

package -> module -> class

Could someone please clear up my confusion? Here is a link to the web.py API I am referencing http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.application

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hope [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes of `application.py` module have been imported into the `__init__.py` of the `web` package (via `__all__`).

In the `__init__.py` of the `web` package, you have:

```
from application import * # referring to application.py
```

And in `application.py`:

```
__all__ = [
    "application", "auto_application",
    "subdir_application", "subdomain_application", 
    "loadhook", "unloadhook",
    "autodelegate"
]
```

Therefore, the attributes specified in the `__all__` found in `application.py` are now accessible directly from the top level import -- `web`.

You can [read more](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) about `packages`, `__init__.py` and `__all__`

Comment: Ah so I can conveniently use the class `application` by just importing `web` and not have to worry about the `application` module itself in this instance?

Comment: But then how would I go about importing the `application` module? If I try something like `import web` -> `app = web.application.application()` I get an error that says there is no attribute `application` in the class `application`. If I say `import web.application` instead the class is still loaded not the module.

Comment: You can't access the `application` module any longer

Comment: One can actually access module in this case. According to [packages docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages),
`when using syntax like import item.subitem.subsubitem, each item except for the last must be a package; the last item can be a module or a package but can’t be a class or function or variable defined in the previous item.`

Therefore, using `import web.application as application` will import an application module

Comment: @Moses Koledoye The documentation you referenced mentioned that `__all__` is a list defined in `__init__.py`. Why does your response say that `__all__` is defined inside `application.py`? Was this a mistake or can you actually do that (i.e., if you define `__all__` inside `application.py`, then if elsewhere you have `from application import *`, the names you've defined inside `__all__` inside `application.py` -- such as the class `application` -- gets exported into the namespace)?